# azure ad group name and member count

Tags: azure, powershell

i have a lots of azure ad group with this format "AA - BB - xxx" where xxx can be anything.

i am trying to do a report on how many members in this azure ad group by display the azure ad group name and the number of its members.

i know to do 1 group is using this:

```
(Get-AzureADGroupMember -all 1 -ObjectId "xxxxx").count
```

how do i do lots of group with same group naming format to display its name and number of members?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get all groups with such a name and then loop over the resulting list like:

```
$result = Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "startswith(DisplayName, 'AA - BB -')" -All $true | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Group       = $_.DisplayName
        MemberCount = @(Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $_.ObjectId -All $true).Count
    }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# save as Csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\PathTo\GroupMemberCount.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>Apparently, the `startswith()` Filter on `Get-AzureADGroup` does not always return the wanted results (depending on the version of the OData language??).
In that case do

`$result = Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like 'AA - BB -*'} | ForEach-Object {...}`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and it will give the count of computers:

```
(Get-AzureADGroupMember -objectid (Get-AzureADGroup -searchstring "your group name here").objectid ).count
```